# Evaluating $\int_c\frac{1}{\sin\frac{1}{z}}\text{d}z$ over $C= \{z\big\vert|z|=\frac{1}{5}\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

Evaluate

> $$\int\limits_{|z|=\frac{1}{5}} \frac{1}{\sin\frac{1}{z}}\text{d}z$$

My attempt: I know that this function has non isolated singularity at $0$, and simple poles at $\frac{1}{n \pi}$. Which ever methods I know are applicable only when all the singularities are isolated. So I tried with Residue theorem but then I realised that the theorem is not applicable here. So now I am stuck. Can any one help please?

I can observe that there are only two poles outside the curve c, one at $1/\pi$ and the other at infinity. Can this be used?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try with the change of variable $z = 1/s$ ?  or maybe change the contour to a rectangle, or both, or use a well-known series for $\frac{1}{\sin(s)}$

Comment: i tried using series but that just gives residue at 0. I dont know what to do next

Comment: and is the Change of variable rule same for complex integral as that for real?

Comment: does it have somthing to do with residue at infinity?

Comment: if a contour $\gamma$ is parametrized as $\gamma(t), t\in [0,1]$ then $\int_\gamma f(z) dz \overset{def}= \int_0^1 f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) dt$, let $\lambda(t) = \frac{1}{\gamma(t)}, \gamma'(t) = \frac{-\lambda'(t)}{\lambda(t)^2}$, $\int_0^1 f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) dt = \int_0^1 f(\frac{1}{\lambda(t)}) \frac{-\lambda'(t)}{\lambda(t)^2} dt \overset{def}= \int_\lambda f(1/z) \frac{-dz}{z^2}$

Comment: ohh thanks @user1952009 . now i will try

Comment: can you generalize to any $\phi$ such that $\gamma(t) = \phi(\lambda(t))$  ? (such that ...)

Comment: I can try answering it now with the help of your comments @user1952009 . Should i post it as a solution or should i edit it in question to conform my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change variable to $w = \frac1z$, we have

$$\oint_{C_{1/5}} \frac{1}{\sin\frac1z} dz = \oint_{-C_5} \frac{1}{\sin w} \left(-\frac{dw}{w^2}\right) = \oint_{C_5} \frac{1}{w^2\sin w} dw$$

where $C_R$ and $-C_R$ are the circular contour $|z| = R$ in counterclockwise and clockwise orientation.

There are $3$ poles for $w$ inside $C_5$. A triple pole at $w = 0$ and two simple pole at $w = \pm \pi$.

- For $w \sim 0$, we have

$$\frac{1}{w^2\sin w} \approx \frac{1}{w^2(w - \frac{w^3}{6} + O(w^5))}
= \frac{1}{w^3}\left(1 + \frac{w^2}{6} + O(w^4)\right)$$

- For $w \sim \pm \pi$, we have

$$\frac{1}{w^2\sin w} \sim \frac{1}{\pi^2\cos\pi(w \mp \pi)} = -\frac{1}{\pi^2(w \mp \pi)}$$
Summing the residues from these $3$ poles, we get

$$\oint_{C_{1/5}} \frac{1}{\sin\frac1z} dz = 2\pi i\left( \frac{1}{6} - \frac{2}{\pi^2}\right) = \left(\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{4}{\pi}\right) i \approx -0.2260419935385651 i$$

As a double check, we can compute the integral numerically on wolfram alpha
using the command `Int[(i/5)/Sin[5*Exp[-i*t]]*Exp[i*t],{t,0,2*Pi}]` and the
result do match.

Comment: why it is $-C_5$ sir and not just $C_5$?

Comment: Wouldn't one map the disk inside $|z| \lt 1/5$ to the region $|z| \gt 5$?

Comment: yess it will sir. ok i got it. so now as the region is on the right hand side of the curve, so integral becomes negative?

Comment: @Prajakta, Let's say you trace along $|z| = \frac15$ counterclockwisely, under the map  $z \mapsto w = 1/z$, the image will trace along $|w| = 5$ clockwisely. This generate an extra minus sign which will cancel the minus side in front of $\frac{dw}{w^2}$.

Comment: @RonGordon it doesn't matter whether we map $|z| < 1/5$ to $|z| > 5$ or not. We are changing the variable on the contour and then pick one region we can apply Cauchy integral formula.

Comment: so we are using residue theorem here?

Comment: @Prajakta, yup.

Comment: So shouldn't there be a negative sign in the formula ? that is neagative sum of residues? As in residue theorem curve is positively oriented know?

Comment: @Prajakta, There are two minus signs, one coming from $-C_R$ and one from $dz = \color{red}{-} \frac{dw}{w^2}$. They cancel out each other.

Comment: yes that i got. but ultimately we are applying cauchy residue formula to integral over C5 know? which is clockwise oriented

Comment: @Prajakta, Under the map, the counterclockwise contour $C_{1/5}$ get mapped to $-C_5$, a clockwise oriented contour, the $C_5$ we apply residue theorem is counterclockwise oriented.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(z) = \frac1{\sin{\left ( \frac1{\zeta+\frac1{n \pi}} \right )}} $$

where $\zeta = z-\frac1{n \pi}$.  Then

$$\begin{align}f(z) &= \frac1{\sin{\left ( \frac{n \pi}{1+ n \pi \zeta} \right )}} \\ &= \frac1{\sin{\left [ n \pi \left (1-n \pi \zeta + n^2 \pi^2 \zeta^2-\cdots \right )\right  ]}}\\ &= \frac1{\sin{n \pi} \cos{(n^2 \pi^2 \zeta - n^3 \pi^3 \zeta^2 +\cdots)} - \cos{n \pi} \sin{(n^2 \pi^2 \zeta - n^3 \pi^3 \zeta^2 +\cdots)}}\\ &= \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\sin{(n^2 \pi^2 \zeta - n^3 \pi^3 \zeta^2 +\cdots)}}\\ &= \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(n^2 \pi^2 \zeta - n^3 \pi^3 \zeta^2 +\cdots)-\frac16 (n^2 \pi^2 \zeta - n^3 \pi^3 \zeta^2 +\cdots)^3+\cdots}\end{align}$$

The residue is the coefficient of $\frac1{\zeta}$, which is $(-1)^{n+1}/(n^2 \pi^2)$.  Within $|z|=1/5$, we only consider $|n| \ge 2$. Thus away from $z=0$ the contribution to the integral is

$$i 2 \pi (2) \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2 \pi^2} = -i \frac{4}{\pi} \left (1-\frac{\pi^2}{12} \right)$$

There is also an essential singularity at $z=0$.  $f$ may be written as

$$f(z) = \frac1{\frac1z - \frac16 \frac1{z^3} + \frac1{120} \frac1{z^5} - \cdots} $$

and thus has no residue here.  Thus, the integral is

$$-i \left (\frac{4}{\pi} - \frac{\pi}{3} \right ) $$

(Thanks to @achillehui for pointing out a crucial mistake.)

Comment: I can not get the last part after essential singularity at 0

Comment: yes, me too. how do you know $Res(\frac{1}{\sum_k c_k z^{-k}},0) = 0$ ?

Comment: for example $Res(\frac{1}{z^{-1}-z^{-3}} ,0) = Res(\frac{z}{1-z^{-2}},0) = Res(z \sum_{k=0}^\infty z^{-{2k}},0) = 1$

Comment: Because the expansion in the denominator goes on to infinity.  Let's say we multiply numerator and denominator by $z^{2 k+1}$; then there will still be negative powers of $z$ in the denominator that dominate the expansion.  Rather, the Laurent expansion will be over positive powers of $z$ and thus, no residue.

Comment: I'm not convinced about your argument on the essential singularity. However, if one compute the contribution from the poles at $\frac{1}{n\pi}$ for $|n| \ge 2$, one get $\color{red}{2}(2\pi i)\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^\color{red}{2}\pi^2} = \left(\frac{\pi}{3} - \frac{4}{\pi}\right)i$, the essential singularity does seem to contribute nothing, strange....

Comment: @achillehui: OK, but where are you getting $(-1)^{n+1}/(n^2 \pi^2)$ for the residue?

Comment: when you expand $n\pi(1 - n\pi\zeta + \cdots)$ in your $f(z)$, you missed one factor of $n\pi$..

Comment: @achillehui: Oh my lord, how humiliating!  Thanks.